# Boost heap element handle comparison and MSVC iterator debug facilities

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, iterator

(Originally asked on boost-users ML: 
[[heap] Singular handle issue with MSVC iterator debug facilities](https://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2017/08/87787.php))

Using VS2017 (Version 15.2) and Boost 1.64, I'm compiling a program which uses `boost::heap::d_ary_heap`.

In debug configuration (with default `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL`), I'm observing issues at run-time when a handle of item on the heap is compared against default-constructed instance of `handle_type`.

BTW, the `handle_type` compiled in is based on `std::list::iterator` as defined in `boost::heap::detail::priority_queue_mutable_wrapper`.

The issue is that MSVC iterator debug facilities break execution with

```
File: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual
studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\list
Line: 290
Expression: list iterators incompatible
```

AFAIU, `handle_type{};` seems to yield handle `h` object wrapping a *singular* iterator.

Below, I copied minimal example to reproduces the issue.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>
#include <boost/heap/d_ary_heap.hpp>

using NodeID = std::uint32_t;
using EdgeWeight = std::int32_t;

using HeapData = std::pair<EdgeWeight, NodeID>;
using HeapContainer = boost::heap::d_ary_heap<
        HeapData,
        boost::heap::arity<4>,
        boost::heap::mutable_<true>,
        boost::heap::compare<std::greater<HeapData>>>;
using HandleType = HeapContainer::handle_type;

int main()
{
    HeapContainer heap;
    auto const handle = heap.push(std::make_pair(100, 1));
    handle == HandleType{}; // _DEBUG_ERROR("list iterators incompatible");

    return 0;
}
```

While debugging the sample, Visual C++ debugger does not show the iterator
wrapped by the handle as default-constructed with *null node pointer*.
Instead, it displays garbage: `((???, ???), ???)`

Is this a known MSVC drawback while working with `boost::heap::d_ary_heap`
or above the `handle_type` is actually misused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read my way through the iterator checking implementation in the MSVC library implementation and have to reach the conclusion that you cannot get a checked-comparable iterator by default-constructing (the owning container will always mismatch).

Worded differently: indeed default constructed handles are singular, but they are so singular on MSVC that they can only be checked-compared to another singular instance. This is fine:

```
 HandleType{} == HandleType{}
```

To get a reliable "non-existent" handle, I'd use the end-iterator handle:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2bb4c2ccdaf5b0dd)</kbd>**

```
#include <cstdint> 
#include <functional> 
#include <boost/heap/d_ary_heap.hpp> 
using NodeID     = std::uint32_t; 
using EdgeWeight = std::int32_t; 
using HeapData   = std::pair<EdgeWeight, NodeID>; 

using HeapContainer = boost::heap::d_ary_heap< 
        HeapData, 
        boost::heap::arity<4>, 
        boost::heap::mutable_<true>, 
        boost::heap::compare<std::greater<HeapData>>>; 

using HandleType = HeapContainer::handle_type; 

int main() { 
    HeapContainer heap; 
    auto const none   = heap.s_handle_from_iterator(heap.end());
    auto const handle = heap.push(std::make_pair(100, 1)); 
    assert(handle != none);
}
```

(Of course the static can be invoked as `HeapContainer::s_handle_from_iterator`)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I'm glad the singularity has been confirmed (yes, I also realised comparing with another singular instance is kosher). Thanks a lot for the reliable non-existent handle suggestion (you've read my actual issue in between the lines :-)). Awesome!